# SQL Server - SQL Query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

- `COURSE_TABLE` : co_id, co_name, co_type, co_duration, co_cost
- `TRAININGEVENT_TABLE` : te_id, te_name, te_date, te_time, te_postcode, co_id

I have these 2 tables in my SQL Server 2012. I need to show details of all the training events for the top three most expensive courses. The query must also show the name of the course and handle any tie situations.

This is my query:

```
select distinct top 3 
    te.te_name, c.co_name, c.co_cost
from 
    TRAININGEVENT_T as te, COURSE_T as c
group by 
    te.te_name, c.co_name, c.co_cost
order by
    te.te_name, c.co_cost desc
```

This gives the names of the courses, and the highest cost.. But it does not give the details of the training events of the top 3 courses with highest cost. HELP??

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT E.te_name , c.co_name, c.co_cost
FROM TRAININGEVENT_TABLE E
             CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP (3) WITH TIES c.co_name, c.co_cost
                          FROM COURSE_TABLE C 
                          WHERE C.co_id = E.co_id
                          ORDER BY C.co_cost DESC) C(co_name, co_cost)
```

Comment: This shows all the courses with their different prices.. I need it to display the top 3 most expensive courses together with the training event details where those most expensive courses have occurred..